# Can I create/view custom maps on the new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

In the old Google Maps, I would sometimes create a custom map that contained several locations related to a particular topic or trip. In the new Google Maps, I can't see a way to create these maps, or to view my old maps. Is this possible, or has the custom maps feature been removed from Google Maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [The New Google Maps, Now Available](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/05/the-new-google-maps-now-available.html) (May 17, 2013)

> "My Places" is not part of the new Google Maps interface. Click the
>   "options" icon in the black navigation bar, select "My Places" and
>   you'll go back to the old interface. It's a trick that lets you
>   temporarily switch to the old interface. You can also click "classic
>   maps".

However you can still access your "My Places" by going directly to [Google Maps - My Places](https://www.google.com/maps/myplaces) which will contain all of your old maps (which are still editable).

You can also use [Google Maps Engine Lite](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/?pli=1) to create and view custom Google Maps.

Comment: Just a little question: is it possible to import KMLs somehow rather than CSVs?

Comment: @Lyubomyr not yet in Map Engine Lite unfortunately

Comment: @batpigandme I make custom maps too! And use Google Map Maker (I am Demeter on Google Map Maker ;o) I was worried about the status of my custom maps, was worried that they were lost forever. I don't want that to happen! I hope Google Maps won't discontinue that feature! Thank you for this answer. I appreciate it.