# Is the new version of Google Maps about to remove My Places?

Tags: google-maps, customization

Google recently started an offer to switch to new version of Google Maps in beta test mode. As far as I understand now, one of the nicest features of My Places is not present in new Google Maps, showing a warning popup saying that the feature is not supported there and I've been switched to old Google Maps **temporarily**. This is bitter news. For example, I really find it really useful while planning my trips.

I have a few questions, but they are pretty related:

- Is this feature supposed to be removed in the nearest future from Google Maps?
- Or if I'm wrong for the removal, is there any work-around to use My Places in the new version?
- Should I backup My Places as soon as possible? (As far as I remember, as a KML file)?

Comment: Related: [Can I create/view custom maps in the new Google maps?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44960/can-i-create-view-custom-maps-on-the-new-google-maps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to import a "my places" map to mapsengine as of late August (maybe they didn't have the feature before).

1. Make a new map.
2. click "import" under untitled layer
3. select "my maps"
4. all your "my places" maps will be listed and you select the map you want to import

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Google has launched Maps Engine Lite. It's the new "my places" and it has a lot of additional features. You can easily import your custom maps there.

Comment: So is the answer that yes, my places is being replaced?

Comment: @Michael: thanks for the reply, it sounds encouraging. A few weeks ago I exported the KML files from the older implementation of Google Maps, but I couldn't find any option to import KML to Maps Engine Lite. Am I missing something? As far as I remember, it can import CSV files, but I don't know how to convert KML to CSV.

Answer (score -1):

A major letdown for people who use "my places" for traveling. I hope Google puts it back on the new version of maps. However, if you go to maps.google.com on your chrome browser, you will get the original browser version of maps and "my places" will be there.

Comment: Well, yes, I still can use the old version of Google Maps, but the question was more about migration to the newer version because of possible data loss.